# Can't figure out why my image wont move in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm just messing around with Pygame and I can't see what I'm doing incorrectly to make the red circle move with the arrow keys. I can't tell if it's in my main loop. I also haven't been able to find very many tutorials on sprite or looping animations with Pygame. If I for example wanted to make a square oscillate for example like a moving platform how would I do that?

`import pygame
import time

## event handling varibles
player_x = 0
player_y = 0
x = 250
y = 250


## screen display
display_width = 500
display_height = 500
pygame.init()
game_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("test")

# player
def player():
    pygame.draw.circle(game_screen,red,(x,y),15)


# colors
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)

### main loop

dead = False
while dead != True:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            dead = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_x = -1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_x = +1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_y = +1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                 player_y = -1
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player_x = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player_y = 0

     game_screen.fill(black)
     player()
     pygame.display.update()
     x -= player_x
     y -= player_y


pygame.quit()
quit()`

Comment: I was trying to make it so when I get a KEYUP event the ball would stop at the current position it was at. I tried changing these values and it made no difference.

Comment: Well your indentation is all messed up. This code will not do anything unless the event is QUIT.

Comment: Also this is not proper syntax `event.key == pygame.K_UP or pygame.K_DOWN` ...  I think you mean: `event.key == pygame.K_UP or vent.key == pygame.K_DOWN`

Answer (score 1):

1. Your indendation is all messed up.

Your code won't do anything unless the event is QUIT... which then makes it quit.

2. Your boolean logic is wrong.

This is not proper syntax `event.key == pygame.K_UP or pygame.K_DOWN`. The order of precedence here is as follows `(event.key == pygame.K_UP) or (K_DOWN)`. Since K_DOWN is truthy, it is always true and thus this entire statement is always true.

I think you mean: `event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN`

3. Lastly, it wont' keep moving as you say you want.

It will only move when there is an event in the queue. You can make it keep moving by generating events. Perhaps with an event timer.

Here is a fixed version, hope this helps:

```
import pygame
import time

## event handling varibles
player_x = 0
player_y = 0
x = 250
y = 250

## screen display
display_width = 500
display_height = 500
pygame.init()
game_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("test")

# player
def player(game_screen, red, point):   # Use parameters not globals
    pygame.draw.circle(game_screen, red, point, 15)

# colors
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)

### main loop
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1)  # 1 per second

dead = False
while not dead:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            dead = True
        elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1)  # Set another timer for another 1 second

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_x = +10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_x = -10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_y = +10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_y = -10
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in [pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                player_x = 0
            elif event.key in [pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN]:
                player_y = 0
        game_screen.fill(black)
        player(game_screen,red,(x,y))
        pygame.display.update()
        x -= player_x
        y -= player_y

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Oh, I changed the step to 10 to make it faster ;)

Comment: This is great. The indentation made a huge difference, I understand now, thank you. Oh and the diagonal movement is much nicer lol